# Supergirl and Arrowverse

Tags: discussion, tags

In light of the news: [The Flash & Supergirl Crossover Officially Confirmed](http://comicbook.com/2016/02/03/the-flash-to-appear-on-supergirl-in-march/)

When this happens, or similar cross-overs in the future, do we need to go back and retag the existing stand-alone media, such as [supergirl-2015](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supergirl-2015), with the collective works tag, such as [arrowverse](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arrowverse)?

Currently, [supergirl-2015](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/supergirl-2015) has a small number of questions, and it would be easy to do, but I'm also interested in our long-term policy where crossovers may crop up.

Comment: There is no reason both tags cannot exist. Arrowverse does not subsume Supergirl because of a single crossover.

Comment: @ThaddeusHowze I wasn't suggesting removing the tag, but whether *adding* the collective tag should be necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Until we see how extensive of a crossover and universe merge this is, I vote for leaving it alone.

It's very likely, IMO, that Supergirl's universe is going to essentially be an "Earth-3" in the Arrowverse, and while they are part of the same multiverse, there will not be regular lasting cause/effects between the shows.

Should the shows decide to merge the universes fully (which makes little sense given comments made about who already has what sort of powers in their respective universes), we can go back and re-tag.

Comment: While I appreciate the sentiment, this really only addresses one part of the question. I get that it's a game of "what if", but it hasn't always been. Weren't some items retroactively tagged "MCU"? How did we handle that?

Comment: Some items have been retroactively tagged MCU, but none of them were *added* to the MCU at a later date. We created MCU, XCU, and even Arrowverse tags after the initial works were tagged. It's not a big deal. We just went and tagged the appropriate works. There was no policy to debate - or even discuss.